Upakarma significance for Grahastha
As discussed in this question, Upakarma signifies the start of Vedic study season. This means from Upakarma to Utsarjana (in February period). The study is required in Brahmacharya ashrama. But when one enters Grahasthya, he has concluded the formal study period (but swaadhyaya--self-study continues).
The question is, what is the significance of Upakarma for Grahasthas when the study is "complete"?
Or, it is about self-study?
